# iPhone -- is it possible to inspect the frame of a UIView in the Xcode debugger?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

When the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint, I can't find the frame of any of my UIViews in there.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT: starting a bounty due to the lack of response.  Just to be clear, what I am looking for is a way to see the frame without adding in extra debugging code.

Also, if the answer is "no you can't do it", bounty will go to the best explanation of why you can see some class members but not others.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. While debugging, find the UIView of interest in the variable inspector. Control-click on it and select "Print Description to Console". For example, I did this on the _view ivar of a UIViewController and the following appeared in the console:

> Printing description of _view:
>   <UIView: 0x25b460; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x26b740>>

Comment: With Xcode 4, you frequently can't get to the view that way, or if you can you get a blank result on output - all bugs in Xcode/clang/lldb. ALSO, this answer won't let you acess the other details, such as "view.bounds". See the other answers below

Comment: Or you can type 'po [view_ivar frame], and you will see:

$1 = 0x00173c50 <UIScrollView: 0x173c50; frame = (0 0; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x175a80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x173e50>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Answer (score 32):

If you go to the debugger panel, you can type this in while you are at a breakpoint:

```
(gdb) print (CGRect) [self frame]
$1 = {
  origin = {
    x = 0, 
    y = 0
  }, 
  size = {
    width = 100, 
    height = 100
  }
}
```

When using the [console debugger](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/140-Debugging_in_the_Console/debugging_in_console.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH7-SW3) you can press the up arrow key to cycle through previous commands. Pressing return without entering a command repeats the last command.

Comment: made my xcode crash when using lldb instead of gdb and running it on the simulator... and killed my OSX Desktop at the same time :D wow

Comment: Also works with a custom `UIView` subclass with overridden `description` method.

Answer (score 19):

Re-formatting @EPage_Ed's answer because the original was hard-coded for his specific case:

At the (lldb) prompt, type:

```
print (CGRect)[view frame]
```

Or, for the bounds:

```
print (CGRect)[view bounds]
```

Comment: This just gives me error: use of undeclared identifier 'CGRect'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Your version of xcode probably broken - apple broke the denugger recently and didnt bothet to fix til next version much later

Answer (score 6):

```
NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myView.frame));
```

Answer (score 4):

In XCode 5.1.1, you can hover over a variable that is a UIView and you will see the following type of popover:

[image]

If you click on the 'i' button, the following type of output will be printed in the debugger's console:

```
<UIImageView: 0xa49ca90; frame = (0 0; 640 360); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa46c1c0>>
```

This is another way of inspecting the frame of a UIView.

Answer (score 3):

```
po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows] objectAtIndex:0] recursiveDescription]
```

will print out the entire view heirachy but only seems to work in gdb and not llvm

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, using the getter method to return the view's frame works:

```
print (CGRect)[view frame]
```

This gives the expected result:

```
(CGRect) $2 = origin=(x=0, y=20) size=(width=320, height=48)
```

But if you try to use dot notation, which I hear so often referred to as being provided simply for  'syntactic sugar':

```
print (CGRect)view.frame
```

You get the following error:

```
error: C-style cast from '<unknown type>' to 'CGRect' is not allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, go to the console and type:

```
po viewName
```

If execution is inside code for the view, you can just:

```
po self
```

This will output some view details, like this:

```
<UIView: 0x9cca0f0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <CALayer: 0x9ccabe0>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer for lldb.  For example, this works

```
(lldb) print (CGRect)[((UIView *)[[[self backIV] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]) frame]
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the short form for print i.e. 'p' to print the frame in lldb. For e.g.

```
p (CGRect)[view frame]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they are just out of scope by the time you  get there.

Print them to the console:

```
NSLog('Frame: %d, %d, %d, %d', frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways to do it if I code for it ahead of time.

What I want is a way to do it that does not require advance coding.  So that in the middle of a run, if I want to see the frame of view X, I can.

Comment: if you are going this way, also try NSStringFromCGRect(CGRect rect)

Comment: Back in 2010 those were ints? I wonder when they changed them to floats.

Answer (score 0):

To get a the frame information similar to the debugger as an NSString, use NSStringFromCGRect(someView.frame)