# How can i get CGRect values x,y,width,height after view is being autoresized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want x,y,widht,height values of view when it is autoresized automatically when orientation of ipad changes. How can i get that?

Comment: This event is called when the orientation is changes. Just get the size there.- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

Comment: @Hanuman Is that event not just for determining whether or not the view supports rotation? Not that it has just rotated?

Comment: ok, I agree Peter Kelly. you can get the size of the view before orientation changes (or should change) by (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation and after orientation by using - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17097371/1463604

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After the view has rotated you should be able to get the new dimensions of the view.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    CGRect myFrame = [self.view frame];
    NSLog(@"height = %f", myFrame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"width = %f", myFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"x = %f", myFrame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"y = %f", myFrame.origin.y);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
   float x = yourView.bounds.origin.x;
   float y = yourView.bounds.origin.y; 

   float width = yourView.bounds.size.width;
   float height = yourView.bounds.size.height; 

   NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,w=%f,h=%f",x,y,width,height);
}
```

Comment: when logging, use the nifty NSStringFromCGRect([yourView bounds]) instead.

Answer (score 0):

after the rotation try.

```
 NSLog(@"x = %.2f y = %.2f width = %.2f height = %.2f", view.frame.origin.x , view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    /*Subclasses may override this method to perform additional actions immediately after
      the rotation. For example, you might use this method to reenable view interactions, 
      start media playback again, or turn on expensive drawing or live updates. By the time 
      this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property is already set to the new 
      orientation.*/
   CGRect frame = self.view.frame
}
```