# Using XCode's brain-damaged debug window

Tags: debugging, uiimageview

XCode is the worst debugging tool I have ever encountered.  Why don't any of the drop-down menus expand the way one would expect?  Why can't I see things like the Frame of an ImageView when I drill down to the UIView subclass?  It is plain awful, and makes a complicated development environment even more so.

HOW do I see the frame of a UIImageView when paused at a breakpoint?  Why doesn't this work?

```
po _minAltSlider.frame
```

When that is the same reference you use in code, i.e:

```
(CGRectContainsPoint(_minAltitudeSlider.frame, touchPoint)
```

Can someone please tell me how in the hell I can determine what the frame thinks it is at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

[iPhone -- is it possible to inspect the frame of a UIView in the Xcode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435354/iphone-is-it-possible-to-inspect-the-frame-of-a-uiview-in-the-xcode-debugger)

Easiest is to rightclick and "Print Description" on "_view", which is at the UIViewController level as you drill down.

And omg you are so right.  Since "frame" doesn't actually show there, how can I put a memory breakpoint on it?  But whatev.  At least you can see it.